# Get WebStorm to stop stripping trailing whitspace on lost focus

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm 2017.3 is stripping trailing whitespace from the current line when the editor loses focus. For example, I type "hello" and then a space; I Alt+Tab to another window and then back to WebStorm; then I type "world" and the result is "helloworld". This happens with all file types. Is there an editor setting somewhere that controls this?

I do have the "Strip trailing spaces on Save" option in Editor > General set to "All" and this is what I want, but I only want it to happen on save, not lost focus. (I don't think this setting is the issue here.) I also do not have any of the "Virtual Space" settings enabled, nor do I want them. I looked through all the other settings and didn't find one that seemed relevant, but I probably missed it.

Comment: Presumably you also have WebStorm saving on lost focus, which triggers the stripping: "save files on frame deactivation", I think it's called. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/saving-and-reverting-changes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm saves files on losing focus by default, that's why white spaces are stripped. Please try disabling **Save files on frame deactivation** in  **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings**